# Angular: How to console error message when API gives error message using Angular

Tags: angular

Angualr10: How to console error message when API gives error message using Angular. Have one API, if getting response I can the print the response successfully. But if API gives the error, I'm unable to print console the error message `err => console.log('HTTP Error', err));` ,  please suggest me...

```
this.http.get("/API/testAPI", {
              headers,
              responseType: "text",
              params: {
                param1: "test",
              },
            })
            .subscribe((res) => {
              userRoles = res;
               console.log("success);
            },
            err => console.log('HTTP Error', err));  //here i need to get error message 
          });
```

Sample error messasge:

```
  {"timestamp":"2019-01-11T10:43:36.990+0000","errorMessage":"No data found","errorDetails":"uri=/api/test"}
```

Comment: Is the API definitely sending an error response to the client?

Comment: if we get server error or no data found, these cases expecting error messages

Comment: The problem is I don't know your api. When it has the "no data found" error, is it sending a 404 (or whatever > 400) response to the client as well? If it just logs the error but sends nothing back to the client then the err function in the angular client is never called.